# Environmental open GIS data for the Caribbean countries

Tags: data-request, geospatial, environment

I'm looking around for reliable data sets that cover various environmental and socioeconomic variables for the Caribbean community. The project I'm working on is trying to determine environmental risks using GIS and data science approaches. I've searched around for DEMs, shapefiles and census data and have found a few good resources:

- DIVA-GIS has a nice repository of relatively up-to-date (5 years old) administrative and environmental data (as .shp): http://www.diva-gis.org/Data
- The USGS has 3 arc-second resolution rasters of elevation data available through their HydroSHEDS project: http://hydrosheds.cr.usgs.gov/index.php
- The Harmonized World Soil Database has processed global soil data, but isn't very high-res or up-to-date

The goal of my research is more focused on environmental change, so high-res hydrological, climate (observed/projected), soil, DEM, etc., data sets that's relatively up-to-date would be useful.

Comment: This link is a catalog of government open data datasets per country (Includes the Caribbean). You might find some more sources here. If you found a good source not on the list, submit it to the catalog :) - http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/

Comment: I wasn't aware of that data repo. I've found a few things I could use for the CARICOM as well as a few other areas I'm looking at. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the nature conservancy has some gis datasets with global coverage, roughly in the areas that you want:
http://maps.tnc.org/gis_data.html